# How to get SQL query Result set in XML format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Ok so I already have

```
select code ,description  from MYTABLE WHERE XYZ='ABC'
 FOR XML PATH('CHARGELOCATION')
```

But the problem is that although I have huge amount of data returned by the query I get only 2033 characters worth of XML and rest gets truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `TYPE` helps?

```
FOR XML PATH('CHARGELOCATION'), TYPE
```

Comment: What does TYPE mean in this?

Comment: [TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT CAST((
          select code ,description 
          from MYTABLE 
          WHERE XYZ='ABC'
          FOR XML PATH('CHARGELOCATION') ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Data
```